# Swift - Insert large data in Core Data

Tags: swift, core-data, alamofire

I am get the results with `Alamofire` from `API` like bellow:

```
let urls = URL(string: url)!
var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: urls)
urlRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
Alamofire.request(urlRequest).responseString { (response) in
    if response.result.isSuccess{
        do{
            let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
            let response = try jsonDecoder.decode(CoursesModelBase.self, from: response.data!)
            if response.status != nil{
                //How can I immediately save results here???
            }catch{
            }
        }
}
```

And how can I immediately save all of results in sqlite like `Architect components` in android?

My custom `objects` is like bellow:

```
{
    "status": 1,
    "result": {
        "cohorts": [
            {
                "id": 383,
                "name": "AAAAA",
                "course_category_id": null,
                "language_symbol": "ar",
                "live_start_date": null,
                "live_end_date": null,
                "live_start_time": null,
                "live_end_time": null,
                "type": "long_term",
                "ctype": "offline",
                "image_url": null,
                "course_category_name": null,
                "have_certificate": null,
                "is_free": null
            },
            {
            },
            {
            }.....
        ],
        "categories": [
            {
                "id": 28,
                "name": "BBBBB",
                "parent_id": null,
                "en": null,
                "tr": null,
                "fr": null,
                "de": null,
                "ar": null,
                "az": null,
                "ur": null,
                "sw": null,
                "ru": null,
                "ha": null,
                "ind": null,
                "cn": null,
                "jp": null
            },
            {
            }....
        ],
        "languages": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "English",
                "symbol": "en",
                "isltr": "0"
            },
            {
            }....
        ]
    }
}
```

I am using VIP architect in my project.

Comment: What have you tried? I don't see any code related to using SqLite.

Comment: @ Joakim Danielson. I tried immediately save result in sqlite with best way.